# Save dtype=object numpy arrays in a csv file containing floats and strings

Tags: python, numpy, csv, file, dtype

I must save 3 strings and one float in each line of a CSV file. Here is what I did:

```
    filename = "results.txt"
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        append_write = "a"
    else:
        append_write = "w"
    
    #I am saving 3 strings and one float, they come from a numpy array 
    results = np.array(["a", "b", "c", 0.32],dtype=object)
    
    f = open(filename, append_write)
    np.savetxt(f, results, delimiter=",")
    f.close()
```

However, here is the error I get whenever I run such a code

```
  raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
  TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')
```

How can I save such mixed variables in a NumPy array to a CSV file?

Comment: Read about the `fmt` parameter.  Default is for numbers,

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify a `fmt` string to [`np.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), like this:

```py
results = np.array(["a", "b", "c", 0.32], dtype=object).reshape(1, -1)
fmt = '%s,%s,%s,%f'

with open(filename, append_write) as f:
    np.savetxt(f, results, delimiter=",", fmt=fmt)
```

N.B. It seems like you want to append your data row-wise, in which case, you need the reshape to get your data into columns (into one row). The `fmt` string should match the number of columns you want to specify.